# SQLDataAdapter duplicating data

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

I'm having some issues with SQLAdapter. When run the following code I end up with a datatable of duplicated rows. I can't figure out where the issue is. I've google the heck out of this and almost all the post deal with removing duplicated data as it's read from sql DB. My db table has 4 records in it. It is not possible there is duplicated data there.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Vehicles : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadResources();
        VehicleScheduler1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
        VehicleScheduler1.DataBind();
    }

}

public string GetConnectionString()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DayPilot"].ConnectionString;
}

private void LoadResources()
{
    VehicleScheduler1.Resources.Clear();
    string sql = "SELECT [id], [name] FROM [vehicles]";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))

    {
        conn.Open();
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
          da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            string name = (string)r["name"];
            string id = Convert.ToString(r["id"]);

            VehicleScheduler1.Resources.Add(name, id);
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}

[EndResult][1]}
```

Comment: You are Loading and Filling the data table. Do one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to fill a `DataTable` from a `DataAdapter`, you have used both here:

```
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());  // remove this one (my suggestion)
da.Fill(dt);                   // or this
```

I usually use [`DataAdater.Fill(DataTable)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx), so your second way, omit the other.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I'm pretty new to development. It's nice to be able to get help, especially when i'm so new sometimes it hard to know what to ask questions about.

Answer (score 0):

> May be this will be helpful

```
     transformerDataTableBindingSource.Clear();
      DataGridTransfData.DataSource = null;
      this.DataGridTransfData.DataSource =this.transformerDataTableBindingSource;
      DataGridTransfData.Refresh();
      this.transfData.TransformerDataTable.Clear();
```